# Jquery table accordion multiple expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need help with some redesign of my jquery code if someone can help me. I want to expand multiple categories without sliding out the other ones. Here is my actual code for sliding one table.

Thnx in advance.

html

```
<table class="research">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="accordion">
                        <td colspan="3">This is the header</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Research</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Partner</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="research">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="accordion">
                        <td colspan="3">This is the header</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Research</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Partner</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="research">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="accordion">
                        <td colspan="3">This is the header</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Research</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Partner</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
    var $research = $('.research');
    $research.find("tr").not('.accordion').hide();
    $research.find("tr").eq(0).show();

    $research.find(".accordion").click(function(){
        $research.find('.accordion').not(this).siblings().fadeOut(500);
        $(this).siblings().fadeToggle(500);
    }).eq(0).trigger('click');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/URh2W/

Comment: can u post it on jsfiddle or jsbin??

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using any tables at all, especially if you're going to be animating elements.  I would highly recommend using Divs instead!

Also, avoid at all costs using inline styles, and ESPECIALLY avoid inline width declarations.

Here's the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ec3hJ/

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="research" width="100%">
    <div class="accordion">
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div><a href="" title="Edit">Editati</a> | <a class="a_del" href="" title="Delete">Stergeti</a></div>
    </div>
```

Let me know if that helps move you in the right direction.  If you are absolutely dead-set to use Tables, it may or may not even work, but you could try converting those Divs back into a table... you shouldn't have to change the CSS or JS.

Comment: i'm using this cause i need it for an admin interface and i need tables, see it in action here: http://mag.webs-it.com/admin/index.php?cat=index&client=1002

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to do.  I made this one left/right, but it's easily changed to up/down.  You will have to set explicit heights, though.

Comment: it's not only that, in your js you still can't have 2 categories opend  at the same time

Comment: So, you want to be able to open multiple, and have to close them manually?  Easily done, really.  I'll update my Fiddle.

Comment: Ok, I've updated it... is that closer to what you were looking for?

Comment: thnx, i'll try to adapt your code with my tables,i hope it works:d

Comment: It should work fine.  Just be sure to put width and heights on all the TD's.  Also, you may want to use TBODY's for the collapsing bits.  Just be sure to use only CSS for your height/width and any other styling and avoid inline properties.

If this helped you and you're able to use the code I wrote, would you please accept this as an answer?